# Using C++ inside an iOS CocoaPod

Tags: c++, ios, cocoapods

I am building a private cocoapod for iOS, and am running into issues with some C++ code. The project builds fine in XCode, but when I attempt to run `pod lib lint MyProjectName.podspec` I get the following error:

> - ERROR | xcodebuild:  /path/to/aheader.h:2:10: error: 'string' file not found

The header has the following first line:

```
#include <string>
```

Searching for possible solutions, I added the following to podspec (based on [CocoaPods: Linking with C++ symbols defined in libPods.a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593292/cocoapods-linking-with-c-symbols-defined-in-libpods-a))

```
s.source_files = "MyProjectName/**/*.{swift,c,m,h,mm,cpp,plist}"
s.library = 'c++'
s.xcconfig = {
   'CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD' => 'c++11',
   'CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY' => 'libc++'
}
```

But it made no difference to the error. Another suggestion I saw was to "use a wrapper", but this piece of code (which is 3rd-party IP that I can not port to Objective C) is already using a wrapper.

How can I build the pod successfully by mixing both Objective C and C++ along with Swift? Any (non-null) pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had to simply renamed the C++ header extension to .hpp, so it was not included by default in the source_files filter. This resolved the issue, as the wrapper was including the header. Posting this in case someone else runs into the same issue.

Update: Nope, it just lets the app build, but using the pod still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly adding stdc++ in the linker options.

```
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-l"stdc++"'
  }
```